Flink - Ververica | Job has finished but no data in sink table
I run a job with Flink SQL script in Ververica Platform. Job has finished but no data in sink table. Job management show no error, and the record has been received. Do it need to wait for data to commit?
I use:
Flink, jdbc, Oracle, in SQL i use TUMBLE to split data by timestamp.
SET 'pipeline.name' = 'SUM_AMOUNT_LCY';
INSERT INTO SUM_AMOUNT_LCY_SINK
SELECT
    TUMBLE_START(COALESCE(stmt.TIME_UPDATE, ft.TIME_UPDATE), INTERVAL '10' MINUTE) AS TIME_WINDOW_START,
    SUM(ABS(stmt.AMOUNT_LCY)) AS AMOUNT_LCY_SUM
FROM
    STMT_ENTRY AS stmt
JOIN
    FUNDS_TRANSFER AS ft
ON
    stmt.TRANS_REFERENCE = ft.RECID
WHERE
    stmt.PROCESSING_DATE = '2024-12-23'
    AND ft.PROCESSING_DATE = '2024-12-23'
GROUP BY
    TUMBLE(COALESCE(stmt.TIME_UPDATE, ft.TIME_UPDATE), INTERVAL '10' MINUTE);



If you aren't committing explicitly, or Fink doesn't do that itself, then maybe check your JDBC connection has auto-commit on. But what happens if you run that statement - or just the query part - manually in a client like SQL Developer? Is the source data committed? What data type is processing_date? If it's a DATE, are all the times at midnight? ('2024-12-23' is a string, not a date; if the column is a DATE then use a date literal like DATE '2024-12-23', and with non-midnight times, a date range.)
